# Segmentation fault in allocating a large array in C

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, malloc

I intend to allocate a large array of size `1073741824` (equivalent to 1GB e.g.) and then read from it randomly but i get segmentation fault (core dumped) for only defining the array as i checked which i do like:

```
unsigned int size = 1073741824;
short arr = malloc(size * sizeof(short));
```

i also tried casting it as follows but still the same issue:

```
unsigned int size = 1073741824;
short *arr = (short*) malloc(size * sizeof(short));
```

also the `ulimit` command returns `unlimited`

so what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You probably want a pointer here: `short *arr = malloc(...)`.

Comment: As suggested by @MOehm, that is not the correct use of malloc. Check: https://es.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc, to see an example

Comment: you are right i am sorry i edited my question that is how i wrote and tested the code but still it returns segmentation fault regardless.

Comment: Did you test the return value of `malloc`?

Comment: But that alone shouldn't cause a segmentation fault. You say that just what you have shown without accessing the memory segfaults? Of course, `malloc` coud return `NULL`, which will segfault if you access it. Did you include `<stdlib.h>`? I think we need a reproducible, minimal example.

Comment: Please 1. use `size_t` for the `size` and 2. provide an actual [MCVE] which is the shortest program that reproduces the problem and compiles by itself.

Comment: no @rici but i suspect that must be the problem. how else can i allocate a large space in memory to an array in C alternatively then?

Comment: Note that `short` is at least 2 bytes wide, so you are attempting to allocate at least two gigabytes, not just one.  It would be surprising for the allocation itself to segfault, but it might reasonably *fail*, returning `NULL`.  You must always check for allocation failure.  If it did fail, but you attempted to use the resulting null pointer as if it pointed to an object, then a segmentation fault would be a plausible result.

Comment: @ali2569, C does not guarantee that you can allocate arbitrarily large objects.  You may be out of luck if you require that, but you could consider trying to use `mmap()` instead.  That *might* allow you to obtain a larger contiguous region.

Comment: i am trying to calculate the time it takes to read elements of large arrays when A. you read them sequentially and B. you read them randomly and then compare the results for an assignment. i was successful doing this very assignment with reading from files instead of arrays although it took hours. but i cant find a way to it with arrays.

Comment: also i do not understand why my question got a down vote. if doing this task is proved to be impossible in C then it might useful for other people too. doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely cause of your problem is `malloc()` fails to allocate close to 2GB of memory on your system. You must check the return value: if `malloc()` fails, it returns a `NULL` pointer which cannot be dereferenced.

Furthermore, your first code fragment defines `arr` as a`short` instead of a `short *`.

Here is the typical code pattern you should be using:

```
    unsigned int size = 1073741824;
    short *arr = malloc(size * sizeof(short));
    if (arr == NULL) {
        fprintf("cannot allocate memory for %u shorts\n", size);
        exit(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the function *malloc* returns NULL due to the large size of the array. Using  *malloc* directly is quite error prone. Therefor it's better to use a macro function like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NEW_ARRAY(ptr, length) \
{ \
        (ptr) = malloc((size_t) (length) * sizeof (ptr)[0]); \
        if ((ptr) == NULL) { \
                fputs("error: Memory exhausted\n", stderr); \
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
        } \
}


int main(void)
{
    unsigned int arrLen = 1073741824;
    short *arr;

    NEW_ARRAY(arr, arrLen);
    /*...*/
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wrapping the check in a macro like this is an anti-pattern -- in most cases, functions that call malloc should return an error indication to their caller if malloc fails, not unconditionally exit.  If you really must use a global wrapper, use a function, not a macro.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Not if the macro is local to an application where this is the desired behavor. If this is not the desired behavior you can skip the NULL check. If the allocation is defined as a function instead you need to pass the element size and then the code becomes more verbose (and again more error prone).